# Can you break a Scala singleton (object)?

Tags: java, scala, singleton

Coming from the Java world, one of the most popular programming texts is "Effective Java" by Joshua Bloch.

One of the many topics in that book instructs programmers to prefer enum-based singletons to standard singleton implementations because most standard implementations can be broken via serialization, cloning, etc.

**My Question**

Can the standard Scala singleton, which seems to be defined by using "object" rather than "class", can be broken via similar tricks?  Or is it protected by the run-time environment much like an enum-based singleton is in Java?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "broken"?

Comment: Basically, with a standard implementation where you have a static variable lazily initialized with check-then-create semantics, you can actually get more than one instance of the singleton by serializing the original and then deserializing it into another variable.  There are other similar ways to break the pattern when an enum is not used.

Comment: Short answer is YES. It is all implemented at the language level and it is free from all the ceremony that we have to do in Java. I am not able to provide link to a resource, but I heard about this on a tech talk.

Comment: If you really want to copy something, you always can. There is nothing that stops you from using reflection, or even `Unsafe`, which allows you to copy memory from one object to another. So in that sense of 'broken', *every* singleton approach is broken, including `object` and `enum`s.

Comment: Do you believe you can get a second copy of a Java enumerated value? I'm pretty sure you can't but I'd be happy to be proven wrong :) and yeah, it's more of a educational question than a practical one, I agree.

Comment: Just tested it, and you can: You use `Unsafe.allocateInstance(EnumType.class)`, which gives you an object of the `EnumType`, but all fields set to the default value. That includes the `name` and `ordinal` fields from `Enum` (which is the supertype of all enums) but you can easily set those using simple reflection.

Comment: That's pretty cool; I'd actually never seen Unsafe java code before.  Throw that in an answer and I'll happily accept it as it shows the question is based on a flawed premise :)  I could just delete the question, but I think the comments here have value for the site.

Comment: Gonna do that really quick. In the meantime, here is a gist that shows what I have done: https://gist.github.com/Clashsoft/4194667937ad9cb27dd9

Comment: Accepted, thanks for the good resources and the interesting conversation ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try hard enough, there is nothing that will stop you from copying *any* object, including enum values, in Java. However, since you cannot create an instance of an `enum` using 'normal' reflection, you have to go a little deeper in the hacker tool box: `sun.misc.Unsafe`. This is only used the create the instance, the rest can be done with normal reflection:

```
Unsafe unsafe = ...; // Obtain the value of the sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe field, using normal reflection
    try
    {
        Object o = unsafe.allocateInstance(TestEnum.class); // creates a new instance of TestEnum with all fields set to 0 / false / null
        System.out.println(o); // prints 'null' because the name field is null
        System.out.println(o.getClass()); // prints 'JavaTest$Enum'

        Field f = Enum.class.getDeclaredField("name");
        f.setAccessible(true); // bypasses the final and access checks
        f.set(o, "TEST"); // set the name to 'TEST'
        f = Enum.class.getDeclaredField("ordinal");
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(o, 1); // set the ordinal to 1

        System.out.println(o); // prints 'TEST'
        System.out.println(((Enum) o).ordinal()); // prints 1
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Additionally, you might want to copy the fields from the INSTANCE of TestEnum to your new instance of TestEnum. This can either be done manually as seen above (by messing with the parameters to `f.set(o, ...)` a bit) or by looping through all fields and copying them, like so:

```
for (Field f : TestEnum.class.getDeclaredFields())
{
    if (!Modifiers.isStatic(f.getModifiers())
    {
        f.setAccessible(true);
        f.set(o, f.get(TestEnum.INSTANCE));
    }
}
```

Of course this only copies the fields in the `TestEnum` class, which in my case has no fields. You might want to copy the fields in `Enum` as well, as they are not handled by this `for` loop.

To give a proper answer to your question: Yes you can break a Scala `object` as much as you can break an `enum`. It all depends on how much effort you are willing to take and how large your illegal code arsenal is.